# Running shell_exec to purge data with php

Tags: php, unix

I'm trying to purge log files at 30 days of it being modified.  I want to use the find command in unix/linux instead of glob in php to take advantage of calling it from the system and not over php.  If I run it this way will it iterate all the files?

Here's what I have so far:

```
 <?php

 shell_exec ('find /path/to/file/*') -mtime +30 -delete;

?>
```

Comment: Those other parameters need to be part of the command, not outside it.

Comment: Ok, so if I change the paramters will it work just like this or do I have to add anything else for this to work?


shell_exec ('find /path/to/file/* -mtime +30 -delete');

Comment: @user2835585 If you use an IDE with syntax highlighting you would've caught this within 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shell_exec ('find /path/to/file/*') -mtime +30 -delete;
                                 ^^--move this
```

should be

```
shell_exec ('find /path/to/file/* -mtime +30 -delete');
                                                    ^^---to here
```

As written, PHP is seeing it as:

```
take the return value of shell_exec,
subtract the undefined constant mtime,
add integer 30, 
subtract the undefined constant delete
```